# Element is not being popped

Tags: c, stack

Here is the `pop()` function, I have written to pop an element of a stack. So far, I have succeeded in pushing elements into a stack and showing the stack. So, I guess my `pop()` function is doing wrong somewhere. Here is my pop function:

```
void pop(int newstack[], int *newtop, int bound )
{
    int item;
    if(*newtop<0)
        printf("\n CAUTION!!! UNDERFLOW");
    else
    {
        item=newstack[*newtop];
        *newtop--;
        printf("\n Element popped->%d",item);
    }
}
```

Taking no chance, I am also posting the `show()` function:

```
void show_stack(int newstack[], int *top)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<=*top;i++)
        printf("%d",newstack[i]);
}
```

I guess there is no error in the show function.

Comment: I'm not sure this: `*newtop--;` does what you think it does. Actually I'll rephrase that. I'm *quite sure* it *doesn't* do what you think it does.

Comment: You need to post your main and pop. show is not required. And *newtop--; ==> (*newtop)--; precedence matters....

Comment: @Gangadhar, error detected. See the answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig : You're absolutely right. Mistu4u, you should check your pointer arithmetics.

Comment: @Mistu4u in this case you might solved the issue by changing statement *newtop--; ==> (*newtop)--;  but in actual sense you need to check your main function exactly how you are passing parameters to the function ..

Comment: My 2 cent: Put all the parameter in a struct. s_stack or something similar.

Comment: Have you tried running this code step-by-step in a debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*` dereference / indirection operator has lower precedence than the `--` postfix decrement operator. Your statement

```
*newtop--;
```

is going to be parsed as

```
*(newtop--);
```

And since the value of `newtop--` is the *current value* of `newtop`, the statement achieves precisely nothing. It dereferences `newtop`, and does nothing with the dereferenced value.

You actually want something like this:

```
*newtop = *newtop - 1;
```

or

```
(*newtop)--;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481740/pointer-expressions-ptr-ptr-and-ptr/18484907#18484907) for details on expressions like `*newtop--`.

Comment: +1 or `--(*newtop);`, no reason to maintain the intermediate that post-dec creates.  in this case its especially good, because `--*newtop` is equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

`*newtop--;` is probably wrong

Use:

`(*newtop)--;`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18756088/1870232)